# rally search user by first character

Tags: rally

I want to realize the functionality that we can search the users' name by typing in the first character of their names. I need to use Javascript to create a custom html.

Is there anyone who has done this before could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example from [this repository](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/project-user-pickers/tree/master/deploy), a user combobox [Rally.ui.combobox.UserComboBox](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.combobox.UserComboBox) searches for matching values dynamically based on the first couple of characters. 
This default functionality displays the expected values after the *second* character is entered.

```
var u = Ext.create('Rally.ui.combobox.UserComboBox',{
                id: 'u',
                project: project,
                fieldLabel: 'select user',
                listeners:{
                   ready: function(combobox){
                                this._onUserSelected(combobox.getRecord());
                   },
                   select: function(combobox){
                                this._onUserSelected(combobox.getRecord());
                   },
                   scope: this
               }
            });
            this.add(u);
        },
```

[image]

If you want to load all users (do not limit the selection to team members and editors of a specific project) you may use [Rally.ui.combobox.Combobox](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.combobox.ComboBox) instead of Rally.ui.combobox.UserComboBox, and set the model to `User`. But to workaround a default behavior where only the current user populates the combobox, use a filter that would filter in all users. In the example below `ObjectID > 0` is used. This combobox will be populated by all users independently of the project picker. This fragment is not a part of a custom app example above:

```
{
                        xtype: 'rallycombobox',
                        fieldLabel: 'select project',
                        storeConfig: {
                            autoLoad: true,
                            model: 'User',
                            filters:[
                                {
                                    property: 'ObjectID',
                                    operator: '>',
                                    value: 0
                                }
                            ],
                            sorters: [
                                {
                                    property: 'UserName',
                                    direction: 'ASC'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: This one works if I use SKD 2.0. Do you know how to realize by using SDK 1.0?

Comment: And this app can only get the editors but will not include all the viewers.

Comment: I am afraid I don't have an AppSDK 1 example, and I assume it will require more coding. It's an older SDK and will be deprecated.

Comment: The example above is updated with a code fragment where a combobox with User model is created that loads all users.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the Web Services API. Here's how I would do it...

The API doesn't allow you to specify a placement of a character in the filter, but you can require that it exists somewhere in the name, that filter would look like:

```
[{
    property : "FirstName",
    operator : "contains",
    value    : "A" //Whatever letter you're looking to start with
}]
```

Now, once the store is loaded, use a second function to filter the records to only those which  *start* with your character:

```
store.filterBy(function(item) {
    return item.get("FirstName")[0] === "A";
});
```

Hope this helps :)